# How to follow or kill all queries running?

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-code

I'm using PostgreSQL [extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-postgresql) for VSCODE to execute basic queries. However, I've executed a query that is running for a long time. I'd like to know if it's possible to track, or simply kill, all queries running through this extension.

I'm using the version 1.1.18 of this extension on remote WSL2 through SSH connection. The system running on WSL is Ubuntu 20.04. The VSCODE version is 1.58.2 running on Windows 10.